# Data Structure in python - Which data type is best from set and dictionary if i want to search large amount of phone numbers in python

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary, data-structures, set

i want to search from large no of data of phone numbers in python which data set shall i use to search from the data type - Set or Dictionaries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very requirement-dependent question. First of all, if this is not an algorithmic problem and you need to run this frequently, then either of these would not work.

Now, coming to your question. Sets are Dictionaries have different use cases. If you need to store something that references the key, then obviously usage of `Set` would not make sense. And if you dont have anything to store, storing a dummy value in a `Dictionary` just to check if the key exists is a bad idea.

Considering your question, have you thought about implementing a `Trie`. Given the fact that phone numbers are fixed in size and character set, you could do lookups pretty quickly using a trie compared to a `Set` or `Dictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

I retain that if you have to choose between set and dictionary you should use dictionaries because they are easier to maintain and to update and you can also search using keys.

On the other hand a set can contain only one copy of something and as a consequence you will never have problems due to duplicate elements.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is check if a certain number is in some container of numbers, you should use a `set`. A `dict` is just a `set` in which every element is linked to some other value. If you don't use this functionality, then a `dict` is just a `set` with some overhead.

You will want to use a `dict` if, for example, you want to map phone numbers to names of people.

Answer (score 0):

**If your use case could be accomplished by either,** then the set will give you all you need without wasting memory on values and should be easier to read as you don't have to account for an unused value.

**Use a set.**